# Ajax call not running code behind controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, post, model-view-controller

So basically when i'm trying to make ajax call it doesn't run code behind it, no error code, everything seems fine but isnt, even after adding a breakpoint, it doesnt hit it.

Roulette Controller:

```
public class RouletteController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Pts(int amount)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1111");
            Console.WriteLine("2222");
            return Json("test");
        }
    }
```

JS Script:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Pts", "Roulette")',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: "1",}),
                success: function(recData) { alert('Success'); },
                error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                               alert("Fail");
                               console.log('xhRequest: ' + xhRequest + "\n");
                               console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
                               console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
                           }
            })
```

#Edit
Network Tab: [image]

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools, Network tab. Please show us the URL being posted to, and all request and response headers for that POST.

Comment: Did you get a `Success` or `Fail` alert?

Comment: I'm getting `Success`

Comment: Please show us where you configured the route for that controller action. Also in Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab) please check what the _response_ to that request was and share it.

Comment: Method accepts  amount as an integer parameter but you are posting as "id". This could be the reason.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy The name of the parameter also doesn't match.

Comment: I fixed it, @mjwills reminded me of route which i didnt have configured. Everything now works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your ajax:

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Roulette/Pts")',
                data: { amount: 1},
                success: function(recData) { alert('Success'); },
                error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                               alert("Fail");
                               console.log('xhRequest: ' + xhRequest + "\n");
                               console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
                               console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
                           }
            });
```

And just for the test modify your action header

```
        [Route("~/Roulette/Pts")]
        public ActionResult Pts(int amount)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1111");
            Console.WriteLine("2222");
            return Json("test");
        }
```

Comment: should the value be a string if it's targeting an int?

Comment: Thanks, it's typo. Fixed.

Comment: I fixed it, I didnt had route configured in my Startup.cs